# Log4j2: NoClassDefFoundError: Static Nested Class

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I have seen that after upgrading to log4j2, it fails to load static nested classes with `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`.

I have a `SingletonHolder` class like this

```
class SingletonHolder {
  static class Holder {
    private static final SingletonInstance INSTANCE = new SingletonInstance();
  }

  static public SingletonInstance getInstance() {
    return INSTANCE;
  }
}
```

When referencing `SingletonHolder.getInstance()`, I get the following exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class mypkg. SingletonHolder$Holder
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:340)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.Loader.initializeClass(Loader.java:285)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ThrowableProxy.loadClass(ThrowableProxy.java:500)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ThrowableProxy.toExtendedStackTrace(ThrowableProxy.java:621)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:170)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:171)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.ThrowableProxy.<init>(ThrowableProxy.java:148)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jLogEvent.getThrownProxy(Log4jLogEvent.java:323)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.ExtendedThrowablePatternConverter.format(ExtendedThrowablePatternConverter.java:64)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.PatternFormatter.format(PatternFormatter.java:36)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout.toSerializable(PatternLayout.java:189)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout.toSerializable(PatternLayout.java:53)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.AbstractStringLayout.toByteArray(AbstractStringLayout.java:52)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.append(AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java:104)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender.append(RollingFileAppender.java:86)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(AppenderControl.java:97)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.callAppenders(LoggerConfig.java:428)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerConfig.asyncCallAppenders(AsyncLoggerConfig.java:118)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerConfigHelper$Log4jEventWrapperHandler.onEvent(AsyncLoggerConfigHelper.java:222)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerConfigHelper$Log4jEventWrapperHandler.onEvent(AsyncLoggerConfigHelper.java:207)
        at com.lmax.disruptor.BatchEventProcessor.run(BatchEventProcessor.java:128)
```

This code was working fine before moving to log4j2.

My log4j2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="error" name="app">
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="app.log"
                     immediateFlush="false" filePattern=app.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{ISO8601} - ${sys:ISApplicationName} ${sys:appVersion} %-5p [%t:%C{1}:%L] - %msg%n"/>
            <Policies>
                <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="7"/>
        </RollingFile>
        <RollingFile name="RollingFileAccess" fileName="access.log"
                     immediateFlush="false" filePattern="access.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{ISO8601} ${sys:ISApplicationName}-${sys:appVersion} %msg%n"/>
            <Policies>
                <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="7"/>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <AsyncLogger name="accessLogger" level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFileAccess"/>
        </AsyncLogger>
        <asyncRoot level="info" includeLocation="true" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
        </asyncRoot>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

And I start the application with the following properties

```
  -DLog4jContextSelector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContextSelector -Dlog4j.configurationFile="path_to/log4j2.xml"
```

Comment: May we assume you've done a clean/build to try and resolve this?   How is your application packaged?

Comment: @BadZen Yes. The build has been cleaned and distribution zip is created. None of it has changed. The only change is moving to log4j2.

Comment: Are you initializing log4j2 from a properties file on the classpath, or manually?   And, is this running in a container, or do you otherwise implement your own ClassLoader()?

Comment: It is initialized from a properties file on the class path. I don't implement my own class loader.

Comment: Ok, then, please post the properties file.

Comment: And please also manually check your zip file to make sure that it conatins mypkg/SingletonHolder$Holder.class, etc...

Comment: @BadZen It does contain the class.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this makes a difference, but I recommend you use either the `Log4jContextSelector` system property to make all loggers async, or `<AsyncRoot>` and `<AsyncLogger>` configuration elements so you can mix async loggers with normal loggers. I would not recommend you do both. So if you use the `Log4jContextSelector` system property please configure with the normal `<Root>` and `<Logger>` config elements.

I noticed that the error message has a space between the package name and the class name: `"Could not initialize class mypkg. SingletonHolder$Holder"`... This looks strange to me. Could this be a bug in the code? Or is this a copy-and-paste mistake when writing your question here?

I'm trying to reproduce the issue but I need some more detail. How does logging come into play here? Are you logging an instance of the singleton like below?

```
logger.info("some message with singleton {}", SingletonHolder.instance());
```